# Silverlight 3 Combobox Rollover Behaviour

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a combo box on a form and when I rollover the combo box with my mouse, the OnMouseOver event causes a graident view to appear.  How would I go about ensuring that it doesn't do that.  What I want is for the combo box to remain white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create a new Template for your ComboBox. This is easiest to do in Blend; right click on the control and choose to edit a copy of the template.

You will want to remove the animations from the MouseOver VisualState.